# setMouseCallback gives an error when being called in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem which I stumbled upon recently. I looked at many sources in here but couldn't find any useful solution. I want to implement setMouseCallback is class based methodology. I deefined the function publicly in `HandGesture.h` which looks like this:

```
void MouseEvents(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userData);
```

and declared it in `HandGesture.cpp` as follow

```
void HandGesture::MouseEvents(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userData){

switch (fingerTips.size()){
    case 1:
        event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN;
        break;
    case 2:
        event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN;
        break;
    case 3:
        event == EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN;
        break;
    default:
        event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE;

}
```

Now if I want to call setMouseCallback function in neigbour function it gives me the following error:

`Error: argument of type "void(HandGesture*)(int event,int x, int y, int flags, void* userData)" is incompatible with parameter of type "cv::MouseCallback"`

I tried to use:
`static void HandGesture::MouseEvents(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userData)` it didn't help. Since I am using vector `fingerTips` which is NOT static, it is not recognized in `MouseEvents` function.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: yours is a **class member** function, expected is a global, static one.

Comment: if you need to use `fingerTips` in your callback, you need to use `userData` to pass it, or better, to pass `this`.

Comment: Which means if I put it outside of `HandGesture` class and have it as a global function with `static`? Thanks @berak and @Wimmel

Comment: Is it possible to use `GetAsyncStateKey` instead `setMouseCallback`. So whenever 2 fingers detected just press the left button of the mouse?

Comment: Duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280220/how-to-use-cvsetmousecallback, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748404/how-to-use-cvsetmousecallback-in-class

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have a question how to reverse this functionality, I know that `setMouseCallback` is the function which listens to the events happening inside of the specific window. But what i want is - to trigger those events when my specific numbers of my fingers detected. Can I do it with `setMouseCallback`? Thank you.