# How to pass several arguments to callback function?

Tags: c++, callback

Using opencv library, at some point I need to register a callback. As far as I know and have experienced, C++ callbacks don't "see" global variables which means parameters have to be passed as pointers.

The infamous callback: `void onMouseMoved(int event, int i, int j, int flags, void* param)` triggered by `setMouseCallback` function. As I need to pass several variables I wrapped them inside a structure. Before passing this structure to `setMouseCallback`, everything is fine, I can access any field of it, but at the other end any attempt to access the fieds results in this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I can't figure out why. In other words how to pass several informations properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use cv::setMouseCallback in class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748404/how-to-use-cvsetmousecallback-in-class)

Comment: One possible reason is the structure object is destroyed at the other end. Please figure out a reproductive example, or describe as detailed as possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I am working on it, i need to format the code first

Comment: I found this: https://answers.opencv.org/question/32888/passing-multiple-parameters-with-the-setmousecallback-function/.it doesnt look very different from i am doing but i'll let you know

Comment: It turns out some forgotten dark code was doing all kind of stuff in the background causing memory leaks and what not. Working code can be provided if needed, thanks!